# Parallel updates to different entity properties

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, objectify

I'm using JDO to access Datastore entities. I'm currently running into issues because different processes access the same entities in parallel and I'm unsure how to go around solving this.

I have entities containing values and calculated values: (key, value1, value2, value3, calculated)

The calculation happens in a separate task queue.
The user can edit the values at any time.
If the values are updated, a new task is pushed to the queue that overwrite the old calculated value.

The problem I currently have is in the following scenario:

1. User creates entity
2. Task is started
3. User notices an error in his initial entry and quickly updates the entity
4. Task finishes based on the old data (from step 1) and overwrites the entire entity, also removing the newly entered values (from step 3)
5. User is not happy

So my questions:

- Can I make the task fail on update in step 4? Wrapping the task in a transaction does not seem to solve this issue for all cases due to eventual consistency (or, quite possibly, my understanding of datastore transactions is just wrong)
- Is using the low-level setProperty method the only way to update a single field of an entity and will this solve my problem?
- If none of the above, what's the best way to deal with a use case like this

---

background:

At the moment, I don't mind trading performance for consistency. I will care about performance later.

This was my first AppEngine application, and because it was a learning process, it does not use some of the best practices. I'm well aware that, in hindsight, I should have thought longer and harder about my data schema. For instance, none of my entities use ancestor relationships where they would be appropriate. I come from a relational background and it shows.

I am planning a major refactoring, probably moving to Objectify, but in the meantime I have a few urgent issues that need to be solved ASAP. And I'd like to first fully understand the Datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously JDO comes with optimistic concurrency checking (should the user enable it) for transactions, which would prevent/reduce the chance of such things. Optimistic concurrency is equally applicable with relational datastores, so you likely know what it does.

Google's JDO plugin uses the low-level API setProperty() method obviously. The log even tells you what low level calls are made (in terms of PUT and GET). Moving to some other API will not on its own solve such problems.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I clearly should have researched JDO's capabilities a little better. I've found a good introduction to JDO's optimistic concurrency features, but fairly little on how to turn on the correct log statements. Do you know, of the top of your head, what logging to enable?

Comment: Logging defined in http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/logging.html and category "DataNucleus.Datastore.Native" likely has most native calls IIRC. Optimistic is on http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/transactions.html#optimistic

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need to handle write conflicts in GAE, you almost always need transactions.  However, it's not just as simple as "use a transaction":

1. First of all, make sure each logical unit of work can be defined in a transaction.  There are limits to transactions; no queries without ancestors, only a certain number of entity groups can be accessed.  You might find you need to do some extra work prior to the transaction starting (ie, lookup keys of entities that will participate in the transaction).
2. Make sure each unit of work is *idempotent*.  This is critical.  Some units of work are automatically idempotent, for example "set my email address to xyz".  Some units of work are not automatically idempotent, for example "move $5 from account A to account B".  You can make transactions idempotent by creating an entity *before* the transaction starts, then deleting the entity inside the transaction.  Check for existence of the entity at the start of the transaction and simply return (completing the txn) if it's been deleted.
3. When you run a transaction, catch `ConcurrentModificationException` and retry the process in a loop.  Now when any txn gets conflicted, it will simply retry until it succeeds.

The only bad thing about collisions here is that it slows the system down and wastes effort during retries.  However, you will get at least one completed transaction per second (maybe a bit less if you have XG transactions) throughput.

Objectify4 handles the retries for you; just define your unit of work as a run() method and run it with ofy().transact().  Just make sure your work is idempotent.

Comment: Clear answer, especially on idempotency. Too bad I can only mark one answer as "the" answer.

Comment: Just FYI - with JDO, you're going to run into user-facing ConcurrentModificationException unless you retry the transactions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you can either prevent the first task from updating the object because certain values have changed from when the task was first launched.

Or you can you embed the object's values within the task request so that the 2nd calc task will restore the object state with consistent value and calcuated members.